# Is the charge of an atom infinite?

Tags: atoms

I am working on a school assignment, and i am wondering if the charges in an atom last forever. An example would be the 21 cm hydrogen line. Does the hydrogen atom produce the radiation forever, or is it based on something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "charges in an atom"? Charge and radiation are not the same thing. Or do you mean "charge" in the sense like you charge a battery?

Comment: The word “infinite” by itself usually means “infinite in *magnitude*”. But you seem to mean “infinite in *duration*”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 21 cm line in hydrogen is the result of a spin-flip of the electron relative to the nucleus. When the two spins are parallel, the energy of the atom is slightly higher than when they are antiparallel - and so the transition is accompanied by the emission of a photon with a wavelength of 21 cm.

[image]

(image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line )

However - once the spins are misaligned, "something" needs to cause them to align again before another emission is possible; otherwise the atom would become an infinite source of energy and that is not possible.

In other words - the atom needs to be excited to emit a photon, and it will do so once; after that it needs to be excited again before it can once again emit.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the atom releases a wave and not a photon, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: So what is the process of exciting the atom?

Comment: A whole lot of physics is about concepts. Waves and photons are two different concepts to describe something which might not fit either one very well. Or maybe it fits both very well, depending on how you look at it. Saying it's one and not the other might be kind of like saying that the US State Department releases a position paper, and not a press release.

Comment: As for the photon/wave question, when we consider a discrete transition from one state to another, the resulting emission is often considered to be a photon which carries the energy as a distinct "packet". But photons have a wavelength, and have wave-like behavior. So while it's convenient to say "emits a photon", the result of that emission is a wave you can observe. Or a particle. Depending on how you do the observing. Not sure that was very helpful - but wave/particle duality is something that the early quantum physics community struggled with for a long time.

Comment: The process of exciting the atom can be one of many things: if you hit the atom with the right energy, it can absorb it; but it's also possible that it absorbs a different energy, and gets back to the excited state (ground state with flipped spin) by a series of other transitions, emitting other phootns along the way. I'm sorry if some of this is a bit beyond you; you mention you are 14, but I've come across some very smart 14 year olds (and your question and comments suggest you are pretty smart yourself).

Comment: @Floris, thank you very much for the information. My science project is about harnessing the ambient radiowaves and converting it to energy. I tried taking this a little farther, by using the 21cm hydrogen line as the source of energy. if this process is infinite, It wont take me long to make a self sustaining generator. so theoretically, is there any way to have the hydrogen emit photons infinitely?

Comment: The hydrogen atoms get their energy from their environment (distant stars etc), and send a tiny amount of that energy to Earth. The sun does something similar - but on a more effective scale. The hydrogen emissions are really just a converting of energy from one source to another. No free lunch here.

Comment: @floris So do you have any ideas on improving my project, and also, is there any way to pull in other radio waves, like a magnet for radio waves or something?

Comment: If you look at the radio telescopes used to pick up tiny signals from distant galaxies you will realize that your idea to harvest this for energy is highly impractical. Fun and creative - but impractical. Adding other wavelengths won't help much - the amount of energy in the electromagnetic spectrum is pretty small until you get to the wavelengths that the Sun emits lots of... but you're not trying to build a solar energy project are you.

Comment: Ok so in case I build something crazy and it works,(which I probably won't), I will post it here

Answer (score 1):

Because of conservation rules, the charge of the nucleus of a hydrogen atom and the charge of the electron around it  exist for ever, and thus the potential well  that keeps the hydrogen atom stable has an infinite lifetime unless the atom interacts destructively.

A h[ydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html) in a particular energy level  will always have a probability to absorb a photon  with the energy that gives the 21cm ( last page in link) line, and go to a higher energy level, and then relax to the old level and emit a 21cm line photon.